# Trying to implode multidimensional array joined with $key.$subkey1.$subkey2...$subkeyN = $value

Tags: php, recursion

I have a small problem with my recursive function, and it is that FQDN is not being created correctly.

```
public function testBuildReverseSchemaNames() {
    $input = [
        'propertyZeroSchema' => 'value_0',
        'communicationPreferences' => [
            'grv3_newsletter_bi' => true
        ],
        'someContainer' => [
            'propertyOneSchema' => 'value_1'
        ],
        'propertyThreeSchema' => 'value_3'
    ];


    $expected = [
        'propertyZeroSchema' => 'value_0',
        'communicationPreferences.grv3_newsletter_bi' => true,
        'someContainer.propertyOneSchema' => 'value_1',
        'propertyThreeSchema' => 'value_3'
    ];

    $output = [];
    $this->buildReverseSchemaNames($input, $output);

    $this->assertEquals($expected, $output);
}


public function buildReverseSchemaNames($data, &$output, $currentFqdn = '') {
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $currentFqdn .= $key.'.';
            $this->buildReverseSchemaNames($value, $output, $currentFqdn);
        } else {
            $currentFqdn .= $key;
            $output[$currentFqdn] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

But the output is like this:

```
Array (
    'propertyZeroSchema' => 'value_0'
    'propertyZeroSchemacommunicationPreferences.grv3_newsletter_bi' => true
    'propertyZeroSchemacommunicationPreferences.someContainer.propertyOneSchema' => 'value_1'
    'propertyZeroSchemacommunicationPreferences.someContainer.propertyThreeSchema' => 'value_3'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was able to find the answer by myself:

Edit: After I thought about doing it cleaner, @jh1711 just answered this. If you repost it I will accept your answer.

```
public function buildReverseSchemaNames($data, &$output, $currentFqdn = '') {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $this->buildReverseSchemaNames($value, $output, $currentFqdn . $key.'.');
            } else {
                $output[$currentFqdn.$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just curious, what benefit is `&$output` as opposed to just returning the value?

Comment: @TimMorton I think it is cleaner, because other way I would have to merge the array. I should try

Comment: It took me a minute to realize what you were doing. I just haven’t had occasion to do so. I was curious if it’s a new trick I need to learn. (I’m just worried about the next coder being a homicidal maniac who knows where I live!)

Answer (score 0):

You should not modify `$currentFqdn` inside your function. Otherwise your changes will affect later iteration of the foreach loop. It should work, if you modify your code like this:

```
public function buildReverseSchemaNames($data, &$output, $currentFqdn = '') {
  foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
      $this->buildReverseSchemaNames($value, $output, $currentFqdn.$key.'.');
    } else {
      $output[$currentFqdn.$key] = $value;
    }
  }
}
```